# Do I need to pay some license fee for Google API place API

Tags: html, google-api, hybrid-mobile-app

I am planning to use below google map api in Hybrid mobile application(JqueryMobile based) with

google.maps.DirectionsService()and google.maps.DirectionsRenderer() api and google.maps.places.PlacesService(map) .

is above mentioned api are freely available for use in android or do I need to take license for the same

```
var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 200,
    types: ['hospital', 'health'] // this is where you set the map to get the hospitals and health related places
  };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, they are not charged. I have worked with them, and that is also what their documentation says - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

> Most websites and applications may use the Google Maps API free of
>   charge. However, if you consistently generate a high amount of
>   traffic, usage limits apply and you will need to pay for extra usage.
>   If your site or application generates 25 000 map loads or more each
>   day, for more than 90 consecutive days, we’ll get in touch with you to
>   talk about payment. Don’t worry, if you go over the limits, we won’t
>   immediately shut off your API access or display error messages on your
>   site.

Comment: If we cross limit beyond 25000 , how much approx charges from them? and I am going to use Hospital details in my application will it cost me some amount

Comment: I don't have an idea about the cost, but if you go through the link, It talks about purchasing it through the API console, so maybe you can try that. 
Either way you can always get in touch with them and enquire about the rates.

Comment: Ankur , is it  applicable for commercial purpose or only for development purpose . i am talking about commercial use

Comment: It is for both, though you can write them an email and I am sure they would answer you better.